# How to replace exception handling structure

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I trying to implement spring security + jwt.I done log-in and log-out methods, jwt filter,provider and web config is configured. So the main problem is my controller and how to return error messages to user, for example if user typed wrong password/username or user account is banned etc.
I got a structure built on exception handling, looks terible.

controller

```
@PostMapping("/log-in")
    public ResponseEntity logIn(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        log.info("[LOG-IN] user with username " + userDto.getUsername());
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> response = userService.logIn(userDto);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);

        } catch (UserStatusException ex) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Account is Pending");
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException ex) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Could not find account!");
        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            log.error("Wrong username or password!");
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Wrong username or password!");
        }
    }
```

service

```
@Override
    public HashMap<String, String> logIn(UserDto userDto)throws AuthenticationException, UserStatusException{
        User user = findByUsername(userDto.getUsername());

        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDto.getUsername(), userDto.getPassword())); //login

        checkUserStatus(user);              //check if user pending or banned
        user.setUserStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE);

        String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(user.getUsername(), user.getUserRoles());
        HashMap<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("token", token);
        response.put("username", user.getUsername());
        userRepository.save(user);
        return response;
    }
@Override
    public User findByUsername(String username)throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        log.info("[UserService, findByUsername]");
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null){
            log.error("User not found with {} username: ", username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
        }
        log.info("User {} successfully loaded ",username);
        return user;
    }
@Override
    public void checkUserStatus(User user)throws UserStatusException {
        if (user.getUserStatus().equals(UserStatus.BANNED)
           || user.getUserStatus().equals(UserStatus.PENDING)) {
            throw new UserStatusException("Not confirmed");
        }
    }
```

Is there any other way to replace this structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a ControllerAdvice (see a tutorial [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)).

It's a special class that look like this

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvice {

   @ExceptionHandler(PersonNotFoundException.class) 
   public ResponseEntity <VndErrors > notFoundException(final PersonNotFoundException e) {

    return error(e, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, e.getId().toString());

   }

}
```

It will allow you to bind a specific return code and response to each exception you need to handle, and it will automatically catch all exception returned by your controller. It's also a good way to handle all exceptions at the same place instead of over each exceptions...

I'm not sure about it, but I think you even can bind it to a specific mapping of your API for more granularity.

Hope this help! Have fun!

Comment: VndErrors has been deprecated. Could you please post a solution with "Problem"

Answer (score 2):

You could add the repose status directly to your custom exception class:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class UsernameNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public UsernameNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public UsernameNotFoundException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

In this way you don't need anymore to catch them in the controller and add the message and the status in ResponseEntity.

Comment: The downside is that this ties a generic exception to the a specific use case (rest api invocation). What if that exception is also used in other contexts? Just saying: one should not violate the single responsibility principle without careful consideration.